# Merging independent modules in Uber JAR

Tags: maven-3

I have **independent** modules (Spring Boot Application with imbedded Tomcat) in a multimodule project. Have requirement to merge artifact of all modules in one JAR. By passing parameters of specific module, I should able to run the jar which should load that module.

---

e.g -
I have module A, B and C with all the properties file associated to individual module.

- Module A, src/main/resources/application-A-.properties
- Module B, src/main/resources/application-B-.properties, -
- Module C, src/main/resources/application-C-.properties

Creating a new module D which dependent on A, B and C as
Module D with resources as below,

- config/A/application-A-.properties
- config/B/application-B-.properties
- config/C/application-C-.properties

---

Once we create a Fat JAR or Uber JAR (say, `D-shade-test.jar`) then I should be able to run the application by calling jar with parameter, like
java -jar D-shade-test.jar --spring.config.location=classpath:/config/A/application-A-.properties

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this question about how to merge into a Fat or Uber JAR, as in the title, or is it about how to deploy individual module, as in the text, or both? Which application do you want to supply with the deploy parameters? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I want to create the single uber jar and want to deploy only this jar and on basis of specific module based parameter it should deploy in web server and boot that specific module. I am able to create the uber jar by introducing a new module and added all independent module dependency (here A, B and C). I am not sure about how to handle resources files.

Comment: Is this more about building with Maven or deployment to your web server? (You set the _maven-3_ tag only.) Handle resource files where/when? Handle them during a Maven build or when deploying to your web server? Which application do you want to supply with the deploy parameters? `mvn ...`? Please update your question accordingly via the _Edit_ link under it.

Comment: The question is: ` Have requirement to merge artifact of all modules in one JAR` why? For what purpose? If you have a spring boot app the application is already the total of the different modules...Or do I misunderstand thing here?

Comment: @khmarbaise - You got it correct, feature of all modules are similar and have future plan to make single repository. So, in first phase plan is to make in single jar and and boot the specific module based on module specific parameters.